# linking various files of html to jsp file

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsp, twitter-bootstrap-3

I Am new to jsp and facing one problem. I have made some html files like **links.html** which contains all the links including(css,bootstrap,google fonts etc) , **navabr.html** which is navigation bar. an many other files.I want to include these in my jsp file were ever it is required but it is not displaying as i want it to display. Please check the links below the screenshots of the of folder structure and code . please help me

folder structure:- http://picpaste.com/4b0d242867c5a004fddce332b85a2bf7.png

links.html :- http://picpaste.com/links-ekBOzEoS.png

navigationbar:- http://picpaste.com/46c7d7835080ad3b0f60bf4c4f70b4f8.png

scripts:- http://picpaste.com/scripts-rmcNmpnP.png

index.jsp :- http://picpaste.com/127f13d41908bbd3bc207fa781163c84.png

plzz help me to sort out this problem...

Comment: All those links are gone.

Comment: no problem i have figured out how to do that.. Any way thanks.. But i have uploaded those pics with delete never checked dont know how or why they got deleted..